# Liquibase seems to run changeset against database twice (or H2 database isn't getting cleaned)

Tags: java, jhipster, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

So I'm trying to run integration tests in my jhipster application, which is currently (by default, haven't made any changes to the tests config) using a H2 database.  I've run mvnw clean test and I get the following error:

```
2018-08-09 16:05:56.340  INFO 276 --- [           main] .f.t.r.CustomAuditEventRepositoryIntTest : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-09 16:06:06.159  INFO 276 --- [           main] c.f.t.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Initializing Metrics Log reporting
2018-08-09 16:06:16.258 ERROR 276 --- [           main] liquibase                                : classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20180725185152_added_entity_Driver.xml::20180725185152-1::jhipster: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20180725185152_added_entity_Driver.xml::20180725185152-1::jhipster failed.  **Error: Table "DRIVER" already exists**; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.driver (id BIGINT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255), middle_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), birth_date date, gender VARCHAR(255), suffix VARCHAR(255), weight FLOAT4, height VARCHAR(255), eye_color VARCHAR(255), hair_color VARCHAR(255), is_organ_donor BOOLEAN, drivers_license_id BIGINT, address_id BIGINT, CONSTRAINT PK_DRIVER PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (drivers_license_id)) [42101-197] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.driver (id BIGINT NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(255), middle_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255), birth_date date, gender VARCHAR(255), suffix VARCHAR(255), weight FLOAT4, height VARCHAR(255), eye_color VARCHAR(255), hair_color VARCHAR(255), is_organ_donor BOOLEAN, drivers_license_id BIGINT, address_id BIGINT, CONSTRAINT PK_DRIVER PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (drivers_license_id))]
```

So the error "Driver table already exists" makes me think

A: Liquibase is running the changesets against the db when it doesn't need to, or maybe it's running them twice?

or

B: The H2 database isn't actually getting cleaned before liquibase runs 
   changesets.

Any ideas?

**Update**: Here are the properties related to hibernate and liquibase in the test directory's application.yml file:

```
datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:TouchQuote2Backend;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        name:
        username:
        password:
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
        database: H2
        open-in-view: false
        show-sql: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
                implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
    liquibase:
        contexts: test
```

I tried changing the hibernate ddl-auto property to validate and it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have Hibernate generating the schema due to default being `create-drop`. As per the [Spring Boot docs, Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".

Set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` to only validate the schema created with Liquibase.